# AppleScript keystroke

Tags: applescript, keystore

I use an app, and I want to get a data from this app,

I found a button on the menu bar > Edit > Optionwanted

I also found that the option have a shortcut (C + COMD + CTRL + SHIFT)

I'm not sure this is the best approach but I tried :

```
activate application "App"

delay 1
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "C" using {control down, command down, shift}
```

but then the result is

> System Events got an error: Can’t make {control down, command down,
>   shift} into type constant or list of constant.

1. is that the best approach to get text from an App ?
2. I can I fix my script.

PS : when I run

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "App"
    set stuff to entire contents of front window
end tell
return stuff
```

I can see what I want there :

> application process "App", static text "445511" of group 3 of
>   group 1 of group 2 of group 5 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of
>   group 2 of group 1 of group 2 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of
>   splitter group 1 of window "The Title is actually not static"

That can be a another approach but the title and Text is dynamic and change all the time.

Comment: Try `shift down` in the list.

Comment: Thank you, you resolved the issue, I can't believe that this was so simple !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.
This is what I got:

```
activate application "App"

delay 1
tell application "System Events" 
    keystroke "C" using {control down, command down, shift down}
end tell
```

Comment: Had the same issue with Illustrator this worked, my example


```-- UNGROUP
tell application "Adobe Illustrator" to activate
delay 1
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Adobe Illustrator"
 keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
end tell
```